# How come my geth require to sync blocks from beginning after update to geth 1.4.12

Tags: go-ethereum, ubuntu

I was running geth under a user call 'ethereum' with this command:
`geth --datadir=/home/ethereum/.ethereum`

It was up to date until today there have a quickfix on geth so I compiled the source code and try to run my geth with this command:
`/home/ethereum/bin/geth --datadir=/home/ethereum/.ethereum`

Somehow it said `Synchronisation failed: block downloading canceled (requested)`

Then, geth started to synchronize again from beginning. I don't have any idea how it can happen even I pointed to same directory.

Comment: I still didn't found out the reason but I tried on another machine with the same scenario and it is working. It is better to backup the chaindata before upgrading the geth client to avoid such kind of problem.